# NGINX+PHP-FPM вообще все запросы перенаправляются на index.php

Tags: php, linux, nginx, php-fpm, manjaro

Настроил NGINX+PHP-FPM, но любые запросы обрабатываются с помощью index.php, например есть директория /a/, содержащая различные файлы, даже если в ней есть index.php, то переход по адресу http://test.loc/a/ будет обрабатываться корневым /index.php, который лежит не в указанной директории, а в корне сайта. Только если конкретно указать http://test.loc/a/index.php, тогда будет обработан правильный index.php. Если же попытаться открыть картинку по адресу http://test.loc/IMG.jpg, то даже если картинка существует, запрос будет обработан через корневой /index.php, со всеми другими ресурсами, которые не *.php. Как это починить? Система Manjaro.

```
# Это код пула
[me]
user = me
group = me
listen = /var/run/php-fpm/jcp370.sock
listen.owner = http
listen.group = http
listen.mode = 0660

pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 5
pm.start_servers = 2
pm.min_spare_servers = 1
pm.max_spare_servers = 3
```

В fastcgi-php.conf уже указан fastcgi_index

```
# А вот это код виртуального домена
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /home/me/www/jcp370.loc/www;

        index index.php index.html;

        server_name jcp370.loc;

        access_log /home/me/www/jcp370.loc/logs/access.log combined;
        error_log /home/me/www/jcp370.loc/logs/error.log warn;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/jcp370.sock;
                fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
                fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
        }
}
```

В access.log на все запросы ответ 200. В error.log

```
2019/08/20 13:59:39 [crit] 25275#25275: *1 stat() "/home/me/www/jcp370.loc/www/" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 127.0.0.1, server: jcp370.loc, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "jcp370.loc"
2019/08/20 13:59:42 [crit] 25275#25275: *1 stat() "/home/me/www/jcp370.loc/www/admin" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 127.0.0.1, server: jcp370.loc, request: "GET /administrator HTTP/1.1", host: "jcp370.loc"
2019/08/20 14:07:10 [crit] 25663#25663: *1 stat() "/home/me/www/jcp370.loc/www/ad/" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 127.0.0.1, server: jcp370.loc, request: "GET /ad/ HTTP/1.1", host: "jcp370.loc"
2019/08/20 14:07:14 [crit] 25663#25663: *1 stat() "/home/me/www/jcp370.loc/www/ad/wef" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 127.0.0.1, server: jcp370.loc, request: "GET /ad/wef HTTP/1.1", host: "jcp370.loc"
2019/08/20 14:07:17 [crit] 25663#25663: *1 stat() "/home/me/www/jcp370.loc/www/ad/wef3" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 127.0.0.1, server: jcp370.loc, request: "GET /ad/wef3 HTTP/1.1", host: "jcp370.loc"
2019/08/20 14:10:09 [crit] 25663#25663: *9 stat() "/home/me/www/jcp370.loc/www/wef.png" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 127.0.0.1, server: jcp370.loc, request: "GET /wef.png HTTP/1.1", host: "jcp370.loc"
2019/08/20 14:11:35 [crit] 25663#25663: *11 stat() "/home/me/www/jcp370.loc/www/DSC_9416.jpg" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 127.0.0.1, server: jcp370.loc, request: "GET /DSC_9416.jpg HTTP/1.1", host: "jcp370.loc"
```

Сейчас на директорию сайта рекурсивно стоят 777 права. Думал хоть так прокатит, нет.
Полагаю что накосячил где-то в location / {} но на других серверах у меня всё хорошо с таким конфигом.

Comment: 1. 777 права - зло 2. такое правило в `location` заворачивает все в `/index.php?$args` в документ рут, нужно исправить это на `try_files $uri $uri/ $uri/index.php?$args =404;`

Comment: Да как бы извезстно что это зло, но проверить нужно было. Правило с добавлением =404 делает так, что даже индексный файл игнорируется, по ссылке ведущей в корень получаем 404, если указать /index.php, то он работает нормально.

Answer (score 1):

Пример файла конфигурации nginx для корректной работы с различными скриптами (не только index.php) в директории проекта:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;

    # Log files for Debugging
        access_log /var/log/nginx/laravel-access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/laravel-error.log;

    # Webroot Directory for Laravel project
        root /var/www/laravel/public;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        # Your Domain Name
        server_name laravel.hakase-labs.co;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        }

    # PHP-FPM Configuration Nginx
        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }
}
```

[Источник](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-install-laravel-5x-with-nginx-and-php-fpm-7-on-centos-7/)

P.S. После изменения конфигурации не забудьте перезапустить nginx.

P.P.S. Конфигурация гарантированно рабочая, т.к. работает как минимум у меня на как минимум 1 машине, точно на скольких - не помню. :)